# Strange field behavior in Excel with data from SSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, tabular

I am building SSAS Tabular models, that I use in both Power BI and Excel

When pulling the models into Excel I get a somewhat strange behavior that I am not a fan of.

The model contains a number of fact, dimension and date tables, all of these contain a number of attributes.

When I initially connect to the model, it shows all tables expanded (see image below)
[image]

I then click the small cog and the "collapse all" button and all is good in my book
[image]

I can now get a great overview of my tables and only expand the one I need for the attribute I am looking for in my report.

Until the first time I add a fielt into my report, then everythin expands again.

Have any of you encountered this issue before?

Comment: That's an Excel thing, which is something that can't be changed (not that I am not aware of). Also, Excel also generates automatically those sigma-iconed tables is certain situations, which again is a fetaure that I don't think can be changed.

Comment: Sucks :( The sigma tables are ones that I create and populate as measure tables in Visual studio, so Im fine on that account :)